# How to redirect all URLs that go to a specific directory to the same path without it in the URL?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I moved an old Blog. Before all pictures were in /var/www/wordpress/cms/foobar/ but now they have to be in /var/www/wordpress/foobar. So I want to redirect all the traffic that is looking for myurl.com/wordpress/cms/foobar to myurl.com/wordpress/foobar.

I already tried this, but it leads to an error dues to too many redirects.

```
RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

That's the complete .htaccess for my Wordpress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Log says:

> [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551540 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3534): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00121: r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551548 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551556 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551562 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551570 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551581 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551588 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551594 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551617 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551624 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:21.551630 2016] [core:debug] [pid 11079]
>   core.c(3541): [client 66.249.78.93:63484] AH00122: redirected from
>   r->uri =
>   /wp-content/gallery/2009-11-22_arenatreptow_placebo/thumbs/thumbs_placebo_konzert_berlin_arenatreptow_009.jpg
>   [Sun Feb 21 03:00:25.077788 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 11084]
>   mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 73.229.109.165:50252] AH01626:
>   authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer:
>   https://www.google.com/ [Sun Feb 21 03:00:25.077826 2016]
>   [authz_core:debug] [pid 11084] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client
>   73.229.109.165:50252] AH01626: authorization result of : granted, referer: https://www.google.com/ [Sun Feb 21 03:00:25.340370
>   2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 11084] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client
>   73.229.109.165:50252] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: https://www.google.com/ [Sun Feb 21
>   03:00:25.340400 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 11084]
>   mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 73.229.109.165:50252] AH01626:
>   authorization result of : granted, referer:
>   https://www.google.com/ [Sun Feb 21 03:00:25.340799 2016] [core:error]
>   [pid 11084] [client 73.229.109.165:50252] AH00124: Request exceeded
>   the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration
>   error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if
>   necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:
>   https://www.google.com/

Comment: Did the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

According to your log snippet, the redirect loop doesn't seem to be from your /cms requests, but rather your /wp-content requests. And that looks to be a result of this Rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
```

where you've made the first pattern grouping optional with the question mark. Maybe try removing the question mark so the first grouping is required:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
```

Other than that, the cms related rewrite looks fine, don't see any problems or conflicts with that one:

```
RewriteRule ^cms/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: JasonTS. did this answer help?